# Как установить холст в левый верхний угол главного окна?

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

Используя tkinter, необходимо установить canvas в левый верхний угол, чтобы можно было нормально работать с ним для отрисовки графики по пикселям.

Но в итоге холст съезжает на 3 пикселя вниз и вправо.

```
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas, PhotoImage, mainloop

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 640, 480

window = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(window, width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT, bg="pink")
canvas.place(x=0, y=0)

img = PhotoImage(width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT)
canvas.create_image((WIDTH/2, HEIGHT/2), image=img, state="normal")

img.put("black", (3, 3))
img.put("black", (WIDTH - 1, 3))
img.put("black", (3, HEIGHT - 1))
img.put("black", (WIDTH - 1, HEIGHT - 1))

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваше приложение изображает точку правильно, но так как сам `Canvas` начинает свою отрисовку с `x=0, y=0` вы не видите свою точку по это, чтобы ее увидеть увеличьте размер вашей точки добавив `put(x, y, x1, y1)`
Пример:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas, PhotoImage, mainloop

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 640, 480

window = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(window, width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT, bg="pink")
canvas.place(x=0, y=0)

img = PhotoImage(width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT)
canvas.create_image((WIDTH/2, HEIGHT/2), image=img, state="normal")
img.put("black", (0, 0, 5, 5))
img.put("black", (WIDTH - 1, 0, WIDTH - 5, 5))
img.put("black", (0, HEIGHT, 5, HEIGHT - 5))
img.put("black", (WIDTH, HEIGHT, WIDTH - 5, HEIGHT - 5))

mainloop()
```

---

и как пример такой же код только с использованием `Label`, а не `Canvas`

```
from tkinter import Tk,  PhotoImage, mainloop, Label

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 640, 480

window = Tk()
label = Label(window, width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT, bg="pink")
label.place(x=0, y=0)

img = PhotoImage(width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT)
label.config(image=img)
img.put("black", (0, 0, 5, 5))
img.put("black", (WIDTH, 0, WIDTH - 5, 5))
img.put("black", (0, HEIGHT, 5, HEIGHT - 5))
img.put("black", (WIDTH, HEIGHT, WIDTH - 5, HEIGHT - 5))

mainloop()
```

Comment: Каким образом можно разместить какой-нибудь объект(матрицу пикселей) ровно в левом верхнем углу (0,0) с заданными размерами в пикселях, так чтобы можно было с ним работать, изменяя цвет пикселей по координатам? 
Способы с Label не подошел потому-что при img.put("black", (0, 0)) почему-то закрашивается не левый верхний, а пиксель с координатами (2,2)